# Runtime exception at 0x004002b0: address out of range 0x10400000

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I'm learning MIPS assembly language and and I'm having an issue with part of my program getting error "address out of range." Could someone please assist me with this.

Error line 294: Runtime exception at 0x004002b0: address out of range 0x10400000

```
    .data
     fileName:      .space  8
     fileContents:      .space  50000
     legalWords:        .space  50000
     correctWords:      .space  50000   

    .text

   importFile:
    li   $v0, 13        # open file
    la   $a0, fileName  # load address with filename
    li   $a1, 0         #flags      
    li   $a2, 0         #mode 0: read, 1: write  
    syscall             # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
    addi $sp, $sp, -4   #make room on the stack
    sw   $s6, 0($sp)    #save $s6 since we are using elsewhere
    move $s6, $v0       # save the file descriptor in $s6
    li   $v0, 14        # system call for read from file
    move $a0, $s6       # file descriptor 
    la   $a1, fileContents  # address to buffer to store read data
    li   $a2, 500000        # maximum number of characters to read
    syscall             # read from file
    li   $v0, 16        # system call for close file
    move $a0, $s6       # file descriptor to close
    syscall             # close file
    lw   $s6, 0($sp)    # restore $s6
    addi $sp, $sp, 4    #restore the stack
   .
   .
   .
   #Fills Word List Until and Asterix is Read
   #a new word is stored every 12 bytes.

    fillWordList:
   li $a1, 0 #positon in legalWords
   li $a2, 0 #currentWord position counter
   fillWordListStart:
    lb $t0, fileContents($a0) # load current char
    beq $t0, 42, fillWordListEnd # found end of legalWords '*' return
    beq $t0, 10, saveWord #new line char found, current word loaded, go  save
    sb  $t0, currentWord($a2) #save character to currentWord
    add $a2, $a2, 1 #move to next position in currentWord
    add $a0, $a0, 1 #move to next position in fileContents
    j fillWordListStart

        saveWord:
            addi $s1, $s1, 1
            mul $t2, $a1, 12 #$t2 contains the position in legalWords were we start storing the currentWord
            li $a2, 0 #reset current word position to 0
            li $t4, 32 #load a ' ' char into $t4 for resetting currentWord
                saveWordStart:
                    lb $t3, currentWord($a2) #load char at current position
                    beq $t3, 0, saveWordEnd #reached end of current word return
                    sb $t3, legalWords($t2)    #copy to legalWords at current position
                    sb $t4, currentWord($a2)
                    add $t2, $t2, 1
                    add $t3, $t3, 1
                    add $a2, $a2, 1
                    j saveWordStart
        saveWordEnd:
            li $a2, 0   #reset current word position to 0
            add $a1, $a1, 1 #move to next position in WordList
            add $a0, $a0, 1 #move to next position in fileContents
            j fillWordListStart
   fillWordListEnd:
    jr $ra

     #-------------------------------End Fill Word   List-----------------------------------------------#

findFirstWord:
lb $t0, fileContents($a0)
beq $t0, 10, findFirstWordReturn #branches on newline character
add $a0, $a0, 1
findFirstWordReturn:
add $a0, $a0, 1
move $v0, $a0   #return position of first word
jr $ra

findNineLetterWord:
beq $v0, 10, findNineLetterWordReturn #nine letter word found *start of  legalWords
j getLength

findNineLetterWordReturn:
add $a0, $a0, -11
move $v0, $a0
jr $ra

        #----------------------Gets Length of current word in fileContents--------------------------------------------# 
 getLength:
 li $a2, 0  #word length
    getLengthStart:
        lb $a1, fileContents($a0)
        beq $a1, 10, getLengthEnd #new line char found current word length is stored
        add $a0, $a0, 1 #move forward one position in file contents
        add $a2, $a2, 1 #add one to wordlength
        j getLengthStart
 getLengthEnd:
add $a0, $a0, 1
move $v0, $a2
j findNineLetterWord
```

Comment: Line 294 that is failing at is:                                                                                                                        lb $a1, fileContents($a0)

Comment: Use the debugging features in the simulator (stepping, breakpoints, etc) to find out why `$a0` has an incorrect value.

Comment: @michaelm Please put any information relevant to your question in the question itself, not the comments.